# Copy files from folder of lnk files back into folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, shortcut, lnk

I have a bunch of folders, each containing a number of shortcut link files to mp3 files existing in completely separate folders. eg:

```
/rock-mp3-shortcuts
/jazz-mp3-shortcuts
/funk-mp3-shortcuts
```

what command would I run (or program to use) to copy all the underlying mp3 files back into the folders of shortcuts that are pointing to them.

I basically want to get all the files in each genre folder of shortcuts to then copy into my portable mp3 player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [shortcutJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat) with which you can create or check info about `.lnk`.You will need it in the same directory with this code:

```
@echo off

setlocal
::set your location on the line bellow
set "mp3_dir=c:\mp3_dir"
pushd "%mp3_dir%"
for /r %%# in (*.lnk) do (

    for /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%a in ('shortcutJS.bat -examine "%%~f#"^|find /i "target"') do (
        echo location of %%# : %%~fb
        rem !!!!  remove the echo on the line bellow if everything is ok !!!!
        echo copy "%%~fb" "%%~dp#"
    )

)
endlocal
```

Comment: I copied https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat into the folder, along with another file with the code above and it did not copy, although it started successfully iterating through the files... some listed here: http://i.imgur.com/uEDzZ1A.png

Comment: @Adrian33  it is in the second comment. Delete the echo in this line `echo copy "%%~fb" "%%~dp#"`  and leave only `copy "%%~fb" "%%~dp#"`  to activate the copying.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
@echo off
FOR /r %%i in (*.lnk) do call :COPYFILE "%%i"
GOTO:EOF
:COPYFILE
set "filename=%1"
set "filename=%filename:"=%"
set "filename=%filename:\=\\%"
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('wmic path win32_shortcutfile where "name='%filename%'" get target /format:list ^| find "="') do (
    set tatgetFile=%%J
    copy /y "%tatgetFile%"
)
```

You'll have to create a bat file and paste my code into it. The file must be located in the folder where all your *.lnk (shortcut) files are. As you have three of them, you will have to copy the bat to each folder and execute it once. You also can automate this and use only one bat but I guess you'll figure out yourself how to do this. It will iterate over all shortcuts and copy the target files to the current folder.

Unfortunately, handling shortcuts in cmd is a pain in the 'a'. That's why we have to use `wmic` and `win32_shortcutfile` here.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm on Win 7 and that doesn't work: http://i.imgur.com/GE9wJCr.png

Comment: Cant you use directly `/format:value` and use variable `Target`?

Comment: @MichaelS that copied 25 files, but ceased with another 54 to go. Also, there are 4 subdirectories hanging off "shorts" and it did not go into those. http://i.imgur.com/BP4vd23.png